# Uniform Continuity of $\frac {1}{x}$ on [$a, \infty$) for positive $a$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, uniform-continuity

[image]

$\frac {1}{x}$ behaves nicely in that it's monotone and the derivative is monotone also. So on [$a,\infty$] it can be seen that the $\delta$ which will work everywhere is the $\delta_1$ at the end closest to $a $ when we slide the $\epsilon$ bar. So for the same $\epsilon$ which $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are in near $a$ the range between $x$ and $y$. 
To find this $\delta_1$ is simple algebra...
$\delta_1= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}-\epsilon}-a$.

So:
Take $\epsilon>0$ Then $\forall x,y \in [a,\infty)$ s.t $|x-y|< \delta_1= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}-\epsilon}-a $

$|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

Is this a good enough proof? Do I have to show algebraically somehow by taking an arbitrary $x$ and $y$ that $\delta_1$ will work?. I would appreciate any feedback on

a) how to make this a good solution

b)If there is a better solution

c)Good tips/tricks on showing functions in general are uniformly continuous or not.

Comment: Let $a := 1/2$ and $\varepsilon := 1/4$. What happens?

Comment: @Chou I edited.

Comment: Alternatively, pick any $x,y \in [a, \infty)$ where $|x-y| \lt \epsilon a^2$ and use $\left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right| = \left|\frac{y}{xy} - \frac{x}{xy}\right|$